# React.js - How can I keep the value in inputnumber and make changes on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

**When I want to enter a new value, it deletes the old value. I want to make changes above the old value. How should I go about this?**

[image: first image => value 50]

**As seen in the picture, after I enter the value of 50, the moment I click, the value becomes 0 and I lose its value.**

[image: second image => value 0]

**Here are the codes:**

> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kykZccS6gC/

Comment: You should only update state with `setProducts1`.

Comment: For which line did you say it?

Comment: it would be nice to put a small code excerpt into the question. For later questions...

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in Codesandbox for easy testing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-breeze-nbiir?file=/src/App.js:3304-3519

The problem is the value of `InputNumber`, it should be the state value instead of props (the value from props will always be 0).

```
const MoonEditor = (productKey, month, props) => {
    return (
      <InputNumber
        value={products1[0][month]} // <-- the latest updated value from products1
        onValueChange={(e) => onEditorValueChange(productKey, props, e.value)}
      />
    );
}
```

I changed a bit of your code to avoid duplicate InputNumber declaration by providing month param in `MoonEditor()`

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the library actually updated the prop value
So a bit of change will be okay to make it works. The problem is just the duplication of InputNumber mess up the value of the props

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-shirley-j7nh2?file=/src/App.js:3370-3513

```
<InputNumber
    inputStyle={{ width: "50px" }}
    value={props.rowData[month]}
    onValueChange={(e) => onEditorValueChange(productKey, props, e.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask one more thing. When I click on the input field, it takes up too much space. What could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is not correct. I just read the doc, the library will update the props and I changed the code. Please see my latest update above in a minute

Comment: . When I click on the input field, it takes up too much space. What could be the reason?

Comment: Apply inputStyle to InputNumber can control the width of the input. You can use CSS class to do it as well. I updated answer and the code in codesandbox, it includes the inputStyle